# Persist state information using a StateMachine in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-statemachine

I am working on project where we use a state machine to realize a workflow. I am having some troubles getting warm with what was put in place, and I would like to see if there may be a better design/implementation to my problem.

I will try to show what we have at the moment.

Please ignore `process_agent` at the moment, I would like to focus on `process_state` only for the beginning. I simply want to create a process and the state machine shall immediately transition from CREATED to ASSIGNED and persist that state in the Entity table (by default I would simply set the current user as the agent for the time being).

There is a table Entity with two information: `process_agent` and `process_state`
There are only three `State`s for the moment, defined as Enums: `CREATED`, `ASSIGNED` and `IN_PROCESS`
There are only two `Event`s at the moment, defined as Enums: `ASSIGN_TO_AGENT` and `START_PROCESS`

There is an endpoint in the controller for the creation of a process that simply hands over to the service:

```
// In the Controller
// mapper is a MapStruct mapper, it simply copies fields from view to entity and vice versa
ResponseEntity<EntityView> create(@RequestBody final EntityView view) {
  final Entity createdEntity = service.create(entityView);
  final EntityView createdEntityView = mapper.toView(createdEntity); //map the entity to its view
  return status(CREATED).body(createdEntityView);
}


// In the Service 
// mapper is a MapStruct mapper, it simply copies fields from view to entity and vice versa
// stateHandler is a custom class to handle an event, see below
Entity entity = new Entity();
mapper.updateFromView(entityView, entity);
entity.setInitState(CREATED);
final Message<Event> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(Event.ASSIGN_TO_AGENT).setHeader("ENTITY_HEADER", entity);
stateHandler.handleEvent(message);
entity.setProcessAgent(...get the current user's id somehow...);
...
return entity;
```

StateHandler handles the event messaging. That is the part that I find difficult and feel I should question. One basically gets a state machine, resets it to the given state and runs it in order to intercept a transition; once intercepted the new target state is persisted to the table of the entity:

```
// stateMachineFactory is auto wired into the state handler
// repository is auto wired in the state handler

public void handleEvent(final Message<Event> message) {
  final Entity entity = message.getHeaders().get("ENTITY_HEADER", Entity.class);
  final State currentState = entity.getProcessState();
  StateMachine<State, Event> machine = stateMachineFactory.getStateMachine();

  machine.getStateMachineAccessor().doWithAllRegions(accessor -> accessor.resetStateMachine(
    new DefaultStateMachineContext<State, Event>(currentState, null, null, null, null)
  ));

  machine.getStateMachineAccessor().doWithAllRegions(accessor -> accessor.addStateMachineInterceptor(

    @Override
    public StateContext<State, Event> postTransition(final StateContext<State, Event> stateContext) {
      final Entity entity1 = stateContext.getMessage().getHeaders.get("ENTITY_HEADER", Entity.class);
      if (entity != null) {
        entity1.setState(stateContext.getTarget().getId());
        repository.save(entity1);
        return stateContext;
      }
      // if entity is null then throw exception
      ... omitted exception handling
    }

  );

  log.debug("Starting state machine to process [{}]", entity);
  stateMachine.start();
  stateMachine.sendEvent(message);
  stateMachine.stop();
}
```

For completeness the following `StateMachineConfig`:

```
@Override
public void configure(final StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<State, Event> config) throws Exception {
  config.withConfiguration()
        .autoStartup(false);
}

@Override
public void configure(final StateMachineStateConfigurer<State, Event> sates) throws Exception {
  states.withStates()
        .initial(State.CREATED)
        .states(EnumSet.allOf(State.class));
}

@Override
public void configure(final StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<State, Event> transitions) throws Exception {
  transitions.withExternal()
             .source(State.CREATED)
             .target(State.ASSIGNED)
             .event(Event.ASSIGN_TO_AGENT)
           .and()
             .withExternal()
             .source(State.ASSIGNED)
             .target(State.IN_PROCESS)
             .event(Event.START_PROCESS);
}
```

I hope I could be as complete as possible. Please let me know if there are any clarifications needed.

My question is: Is there a better design to implement this state machine, or is what one can see here a reasonable approach ?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess your workflow is bound to "agent" - so an agent starts a workflow and you want to persist the state of the workflow per agent. Now I don't know if an agent can start multiple workflow instances and progress them in parallel, so the below suggestion might need to be re-adjusted for those cases.

The straight forward approach would be to have a SM instance per agent (and per workflow if there are multiple workflow instances possible).
When an agent starts working with a workflow you must identify if it is a completely new workflow or an existing one in a particular state.

if it is a new workflow - return a new SM on a starting state and send the required event.

if it is an existing workflow, you need to create a SM and feed to the SM the current workflow state and do the necessary transitions upon SM initialization, before returning it to the service caller. The state should be previously persisted to a datastore.

I don't know your domain, so the state could be persisted as part of some Workflow entity or Agent entity or something else - depends on the app context.

There are different approaches on who is persisting the state in the DB.

**A)** The SM can be responsible for this (e.g. upon receiving an event the SM will extract the necessary state information and context (e.g. DB entity ID) from the event and persist it in the DB for that Entity ID and then transition to the next state).

**B)** A Service XYZ that is "orchestrating" the SM can be responsible for this (e.g. a Service XYZ calls "persist" on another repository service and if it is a successful operation, then the Service XYZ send the necessary event to the SM - then the SM only handles the transition to the next state).